# 'CustomerForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, forms

I have been trying to submit login information to a database in Django using a form bu keep getting an error that I have tried to fix. found similar answers here but didn't work for me. Can someone please help me

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

#from customers.views import home_view
#from customers.views import design_view
from customers.views import CustomerForm

urlpatterns = [
    #path('',home_view,name='home'),
    path('for/',CustomerForm,name='form'),
    #path('design/',design_view,name='design'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

template/design.html

```
<h1>THIS IS ABOUT MY NAME</h1>
<form>{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="save">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Login
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Login
        fields=['email','password']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from .forms import CustomerForm
from .models import Login

def Login_view(request):
    #return HttpResponse("<h1>this is the home page</h1>")
    forme = CustomerForm(request.POST)
    if forme.is_valid():
        forme.save()
    #log=Login.objects.get(id=1)
    context={
        'form':forme
    }
    return render(request,"more/design.html",context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Login(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

errorcode

```
Internal Server Error: /for/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Henry R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Henry R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Henry R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'CustomerForm' object has no attribute 'get'
[27/Nov/2019 01:09:29] "GET /for/ HTTP/1.1" 500 58312
```

Comment: you need to re-paste your views.py. currently it is the same as forms.py

Comment: i had copied the wrong views.py, bu ti have edited it. Your help would be appreciated

Comment: try change```path('for/',CustomerForm,name='form'),```  to : ```path('for/', Login_view, name='login_view'),```

Comment: Did the above solution work?. @ha-neul consider posting this as a solution.